# remove single quote from internal command result

Tags: bash

I am trying to run bash command

```
gcloud compute ssh "instanceName" -- "sudo reboot"
```

with another internal bash command (which just gives me the name of the instance)

```
gcloud compute instances list | grep auth- | awk '{print $1}')
```

So it prints `auth-tqcl` - the instance name without any quotes. This is good.

The whole command looks like this:

```
 gcloud compute ssh "$(gcloud compute instances list | grep auth- | awk '{print $1}')" -- "sudo reboot"
```

And I have error:

> Invalid value 'auth-tqcl'. Values must match the following regular
>   expression.

So looks like I have extra `'` characters before and after instance name: `'auth-tqcl'`:

```
 gcloud compute ssh 'auth-tqcl' -- 'sudo reboot'
```

But when I copy paste this ready command and run it without internal bash command, it works fine.

So my question is: how to get rid of extra `'` in `'auth-tqcl'` when I execute the bash command

```
$(gcloud compute instances list | grep auth- | awk '{print $1}')
```

inside another bash command.

I am using a standard terminal in mac os.

## Update

Here is the proof of extra quote:

```
$ set -x; gcloud compute ssh "$(gcloud compute instances list | grep auth- | awk '{print $1}')" -- "sudo reboot"; set +x;
++(:1):  myMac $ gcloud compute instances list
++(:1):  myMac $ grep auth-
++(:1):  myMac $ awk '{print $1}'
+(:9):  myMac $ gcloud compute ssh 'auth-tqcl' -- 'sudo reboot'
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value 'auth-tqcl'. Values must match the following regular expression: '[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?'
```

## Update 2

`gcloud compute instances list | grep auth-` response is without quotes:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list | grep auth-
auth-tqcl    europe-west1-b  n1-standard-1               xx.xxx.x.x   xx.xxx.xx.xx    RUNNING
```

## Update 3

```
$ gcloud compute instances list | grep auth- | awk '{print $1}' | od -c
0000000  033   [   1   ;   3   7   ;   4   1   m 033   [   K   a   u   t
0000020    h   - 033   [   m 033   [   K   t   q   c   l  \n            
0000035
```

Comment: "So looks like I have extra ' characters before and after instance name:" According to what?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams updated output with +x above

Comment: That output doesn't show single quotes in the text itself, since the output from text that actually *does* have single quotes looks very different. `+ echo ''\''123-456'\'''`

Comment: I assumed there is a quote there because I don't see any other reason why 'auth-tqcl' would not match regex '[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?'. Just wondering how to check my assumption. It could be trailing next line char after awk as well. This is just pure guess

Comment: is `gcloud compute instances list` returning `'auth-tqcl'` with the quotes? It'd be interesting to see the output of `gcloud compute instances list | grep auth-`

Comment: @JeffSchaller it returns result without quotes, added update above

Comment: Add the output of `gcloud compute instances list | grep auth- | awk '{print $1}' | od -c`, please.

Comment: So `gcloud`'s output has colour, even if its output goes to a pipe. You should probably do `gcloud compute instances list --format=csv` and parse it as a CSV (or `--format=json` and parse with `jq`). See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I need to disable grep colors:

this works:

```
gcloud compute ssh "$(gcloud compute instances list | GREP_OPTIONS= grep auth- | awk '{print $1}')" -- "sudo reboot"
```

Comment: Do you have `GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'` set? You might want to consider changing that to `--color=auto`, just to avoid things like this...

Comment: awesome, changed it to auto, now my initial command works ` gcloud compute ssh "$(gcloud compute instances list | grep auth- | awk '{print $1}')" -- "sudo reboot"
`.